# Different static member values on derived classes

Tags: c#

When I write:

```
public class A
{
    public static int v;
}
public class B : A { }
public class C : A { }
```

Values of `A.v`, `B.v` and `C.v` are all same.
How can I make them to store different static values?

Comment: You can't, that's one of the aspects of being static.

Comment: If you don't want that effect, why do you derive from the same class then?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: Looks like you need instance behavior... Why do you want to make it static?

Comment: For example B.v is going to be used by its instances and it will be the same for all B instances. But C.v should be different. And I'm deriving them because I need to... There will be plenty of methods that should be derived from A.

Comment: (Duplicate of quite a few questions, in fact. I answered one last week, but I can't find it now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Values of A.v, B.v and C.v are all same.
>   How can I make them to store different static values?

You can't; `A.v`, `B.v` and `C.v` all refer to the same static field, so they can't have different values.

A possible workaround would be to redeclare `v` in `B` and `C`:

```
public class A
{
    public static int v;
}
public class B : A
{
    public static new int v;
}
public class C : A
{
    public static new int v;
}
```

If you do that, `A.v`, `B.v` and `C.v` will effectively refer to different fields, so they can have different values.

(Note the `new` modifier; it tells the compiler that you're intentionally hiding the member from the base class)

Depending on your exact needs, faester's solution might be better.

Comment: It seems it is not possible without redeclaring them or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Dont make them static but use a virtual readonly property to obtain the same effect:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int v { get { return 1; } }
}

public class B : A { }

public class C : A
{
    public override int v
    {
        get { return 2; } 
    }
}
```